# Language Hierarchy module bug or is it me?

Tags: i18n-l10n

Not sure if this is the right place to go with this question: However, before I file an issue with this, I'm wondering if it is something I'm missing or doing wrong.

The problem. Given a language (lets say Spanish), I have defined another custom language (Spanish, Mexico)
From /admin/config/regional/language, I nest Spanish, Mexico with Spanish as a fallback.

[image]

Next, I define a translation for Spanish, Mexico.

**Expected Result**: a translation for that term unique to Spanish, Mexico, and a separate translation for Spanish.

I have created a fresh install of Drupal 8.9.9 and have only installed https://www.drupal.org/project/language_hierarchy (V.2.0.0-rc2). Also tried 2.x-dev (same error)

**Actual Result:** the Spanish, Mexico translation overwrites the Spanish.

[image]

Comment: So you translate a string to Spanish, and then you translate the same string to Spanish, Mexico, and the Spanish, Mexico string overwrites the original Spanish string?

Comment: Yes - (well, as soon as you turn (add) Spanish as a language, it comes prepopulate with translations.  I add es-MX as a custom language. When I made Spanish the default, it populated all the fields in es-MX with ES. 
THEN
changing a field on es-MX overwrites that same field on the fall back (ES)